# how to understand the return value in java's recursion

Tags: java, recursion, return-value

I have coded a program with java language，but the answer is never the right one, I use the recursion to complete the program,but the return value in the method is not the one I want,it can be return twice when I debug it.if there anyone who can explain it for me ,Thanks  a lot.

```
/**
 * addDigits:
 * Given a non-negative integer num * repeatedly add all 
 * its digits until the result has only one digit.
 * For example:
 * Given num = 38, the process is like: 
 * 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2 has only one digit, return it.
 * it should be 2,but the answer is 11,may anyone help me with the problem?      
 * thanks
 */
public class Test{
    public int addDigits(int num) {
        String str = String.valueOf(num);
        String[] temp = new String[str.length()];
        int tempInt = 0;
        if (str.length() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                temp[i] = str.substring(i, i + 1);
                tempInt += Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
            }
            addDigits(tempInt);
        } else {
            tempInt = num;
        }
        return tempInt;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        int i = test.addDigits(38);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code you have written, you aren't doing anything with the result of the recursive call. You are correctly setting your tempInt to 11, then returning it. You want to be returning the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `addDigits(tempInt);` recursively inside your function,
you're not doing anything with the result, you're just throwing it away.
Changing the line to this will fix it:

```
tempInt = addDigits(tempInt);
```

Also, you can solve this more elegantly and without converting to string:

```
if (num < 10) {
    return num;
}

int sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
return addDigits(sum);
```

Comment: it does solve the problem,but when I debug it ,why does the comment "return tempInt;"  be used twice?

Comment: Because of `addDigits(tempInt)` executes it a second time

Comment: @Joker because `addDigits` is called as many times as are required until there is only a single digit; just like your description explains.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forgot to capture the return value from every invocation to `addDigits()`, replace your code with the following line:

```
 tempInt = addDigits(tempInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is when you keep calling the code over and over, I tried it with a do loop instead:

```
 public int addDigits(int num) {
   int tempInt;
   String str;

     do 
   {
        str = String.valueOf(num);
    String[] temp = new String[str.length()];
    tempInt = 0;
    if (str.length() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            temp[i] = str.substring(i, i + 1);
            tempInt += Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        }
        num = tempInt;
      } 
    } while (str.length() > 1);
   tempInt = num;
    return tempInt;
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Temp test = new Temp();
    int i = test.addDigits(38);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

}

Yours was returning the value back to where it had called it over and over not back to main until like the 3rd or 4th time.

Comment: yes, because i call it for much time,so the comment called for much time.